# Way to enable auto spell correct on windows 10 with any browser?

Tags: windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge, autocorrect, facebook-chat

My typing is really bad so I have been trying to enable auto correct for windows 10 while using a web browser(mainly for facebook chat). I did a google search and all posts are on how to disable it. I used this method(windows 10 typing settings/hardware keyboard) but instead used it to enable it and it doesnt work in browsers(the new edge/chrome/firefox). Did they remove this feature because all the posts I saw where people wanted to disable it were from 2018 or older and I am having the opposite problem - I want it enabled. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Chromium Edge (current) or Legacy Edge?

Comment: Chromium edge but im 99% sure I tried it with the old one too and it didint work either in the past

Comment: What version of edge?

Comment: Newest one. Just updated before I replied

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome has a built in spell checker. Go to Settings > Advanced, go to Languages and click Spell Check to expand menu. Then turn on the language you want spell check for. Or you can use the Grammarly extension, which is very nice.

For Mozilla firefox go to about:preference > Advanced > General > Browsing and turn on "Check my spelling as I type".

Comment: Spell checker or auto correct?

Comment: Spell checker and auto correct.

Comment: Just tried the built in options on both chrome and firefox as well as Grammarly and none of them worked. Mabe its something to do with facebook?